# PHP Startup:Unable to start dynamic library

Tags: php, pthreads

I was trying to add PHP pthreads , following steps are completed

Extract the zip -

- Move `php_pthreads.dll` to the `bin\php\ext\` directory.
- Move `pthreadVC2.dll` to the `bin\php\` directory.
- Move `pthreadVC2.dll` to the `bin\apache\bin` directory.
- Move `pthreadVC2.dll` to the `C:\windows\system32` directory.
- Open `php\php.ini` and add `extension=php_pthreads.dll`

After those steps, restating causes an error

> PHP Startup:unable to load dynamic library 'c:\xamp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll' -%1 is not a valid  Win32 application

Comment: are you certain `php_pthreads.dll` is for your windows version and architecture?

Comment: @castis my pc is 64 bit windows 8 , Downloaded pthread file was "php_pthreads-2.0.9-5.5-ts-vc11-x64"

Comment: Do you have the [*Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012*](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed? It's required for VC11 builds. Source: [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/)

Comment: Hi @Midhun, I have the same isse. Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the Non-Thread Safe(nts) version for your php version and architecture